# mapbox navigation ondidfinishloadingstyle exception

Tags: android, mapbox, illegalargumentexception, mapbox-android

trying to build a navigation on android using this tutorial https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/android-navigation-sdk/#customize-the-style

but it throws me this exception
[image: ex]

when I press the navigation button. The road shows correctly, but only using google maps api for getting my loccation.

Thanks for any advice.

my code:

```
`   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.access_token2));
        getLocationPermission();
        manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav);
        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getDeviceLocation();

        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }
    private void getDeviceLocation(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLoc");
        if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();
        }
        FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        try{
            if(mLocationPermissionsGranted){
                final Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                location.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        curLoc = (Location) task.getResult();
                        Log.d(TAG, "found location" + curLoc);
                    }
                });
            }
        }catch (SecurityException e){
            Timber.e("getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: %s", e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    private void getLocationPermission(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission");
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Timber.d("Can get FINE LOCATION");
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Timber.d("Can get COARSE LOCATION");
                mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
            }else{
                Timber.d("Can't get COARSE LOCATION");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions,
                        LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
            }
        }else{
            Timber.d("Can't get FINE LOCATION");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
            PermissionUtils.requestPermission(this, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, true);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRequest");
        mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;

        switch(requestCode){
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:{
                if(grantResults.length > 0){
                    for (int grantResult : grantResults) {
                        if (grantResult != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
                            Log.d(TAG, "permission failed");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "permission granted");
                    mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialog, id) -> startActivity(new Intent(
                        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)))
                .setNegativeButton("No", (dialog, id) -> dialog.cancel());
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;
        LatLng origin = new LatLng(curLoc.getLatitude(), curLoc.getLongitude());
        CameraPosition position = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(origin)
                .zoom(15)
                .tilt(20)
                .build();
        mapboxMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position), 5000);
        mapboxMap.setStyle(getString(R.string.navigation_guidance_day), new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
            @Override
            public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                addDestinationIconSymbolLayer(style);
                Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
                Places place = data.getParcelable("place");
                LatLng destination = new LatLng(place.getLocation().getLatitude(),
                        place.getLocation().getLongitude());
                Point destinationPoint = Point.fromLngLat(destination.getLongitude(),
                        destination.getLatitude());
                Point originPoint = Point.fromLngLat(curLoc.getLongitude(), curLoc.getLatitude());
                GeoJsonSource source = mapboxMap.getStyle().getSourceAs("destination-source-id");
                if (source != null) {
                    source.setGeoJson(Feature.fromGeometry(destinationPoint));
                }
                getRoute(originPoint, destinationPoint);
                button = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
                button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
                    boolean simulateRoute = true;
                    NavigationLauncherOptions options = NavigationLauncherOptions.builder()
                            .directionsRoute(currentRoute)
                            .shouldSimulateRoute(simulateRoute)
                            .build();

                    NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(Navigate.this, options);
                });
                button.setEnabled(true);

            }
        });
    }

    private void addDestinationIconSymbolLayer(@NonNull Style loadedMapStyle) {
        loadedMapStyle.addImage("destination-icon-id",
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.mapbox_marker_icon_default));
        GeoJsonSource geoJsonSource = new GeoJsonSource("destination-source-id");
        loadedMapStyle.addSource(geoJsonSource);
        SymbolLayer destinationSymbolLayer = new SymbolLayer("destination-symbol-layer-id",
                "destination-source-id");
        destinationSymbolLayer.withProperties(
                iconImage("destination-icon-id"),
                iconAllowOverlap(true),
                iconIgnorePlacement(true)
        );
        loadedMapStyle.addLayer(destinationSymbolLayer);
    }

    private void getRoute(Point origin, Point destination) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getRoute");
        NavigationRoute.builder(this)
                .accessToken(getString(R.string.access_token2))
                .origin(origin)
                .destination(destination)
                .build()
                .getRoute(new Callback<DirectionsResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<DirectionsResponse> call,
                                           Response<DirectionsResponse> response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Response code: " + response.code());
                        if (response.body() == null) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "No routes found, make sure you set the right user and access token.");
                            return;
                        } else if (response.body().routes().size() < 1) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "No routes found");
                            return;
                        }

                        currentRoute = response.body().routes().get(0);

                        if (navigationMapRoute != null) {
                            navigationMapRoute.removeRoute();
                        } else {
                            navigationMapRoute = new NavigationMapRoute(null, mapView,
                                    mapboxMap, R.style.NavigationMapRoute);
                        }
                        navigationMapRoute.addRoute(currentRoute);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Throwable throwable) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + throwable.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }
```

`

Comment: share your code

Comment: I edited the post and added my code

Comment: Is the exception raised at runtime or buildtime? If it's at runtime, is it after a specific action is taken? The error you've posted states that you're attempting to add an element with an improperly defined radius, but it's hard to tell from your code where that might be happening.

Comment: I change the code a little from the time of my question, but the error is still the same, it happens at runtime, when i press the navigation button. before that, i can see the road, but navigation cant start. I think, there the mapbox have problem with getting my location, because before i get my location from google, this error occured when i was trying to get the route.

Comment: I just found out, that maybe this error didnt cause the crash but this did:

02-26 21:18:39.693 757-862/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '429e9990 com.example.misa.googlemaps/com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.MapboxNavigationActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

02-26 21:18:39.960 31860-31860/? E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)

Comment: Just letting you know, that the problem was because of old version of android in the testing phone